# Python super() not work with Enum parameter

Tags: python, super

I have the code that

```
from enum import Enum

EventType = Enum('EventType', ('TIMER_EVENT', 'LOG_EVENT'))


class Event(object):
    def __init__(self, type_=None):
        self.type_ = type_


class LogEvent(Event):
    def __int__(self):
        super(LogEvent, self).__init__(EventType.LOG_EVENT)


class TimerEvent(Event):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TimerEvent, self).__init__(EventType.TIMER_EVENT)

print(LogEvent().type_)
print(TimerEvent().type_)
```

The result is

```
None
EventType.TIMER_EVENT
```

the `super()` function are almost the same in class `LogEvent` and `TimerEvnet`

but why the `super()` function of `LogEvent` doesn't work?

My python version is 3.6.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `LogEvent` class you have `def __int__` instead of `def __init__`.

Comment: I am sorry for asking this question. Thank you!

Comment: Don't worry about it, happens all of us. If it helped, please mark it as correct :)